# Can't update from NULL to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, dbo

Hi i'm using this command to left join a table with another table that has a little more records but it keep printing NULL. I want that NULL to become 0.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1

Left JOIN Table2 ON TABLE1.ID=Table2.IDRel

UPDATE Table2 SET IDRel = 0 where IDRel = NULL
```

Comment: Use `IS NULL`, nothing is equal or unequal to `NULL`.

Comment: as @xQbert answered, the problem is likely to be that you have rows in Table1 with no matching rows in Table2, so the update won't make sense - you probably just want to use his solution of coalescing the null values in the LEFT JOIN output to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update should not be needed.
As you said Table2 `has a little more records` that's the key thing here, that means that for any row from Table1 for which no matching `IDRel` value could be found that column (`IDRel`) will stay `NULL`.

Now you could for example use `ISNULL(IDRel, 0)` to replace null value with 0, but maybe an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN` could get you the right result throwing out all rows that could not be matched...

However... If you really were to update that column it would only work if you did the correct comparison against `NULL` (that is `IS` not `=`) that would mean changing your update query into:

`UPDATE Table2 SET IDRel = 0 where IDRel IS NULL`

Comment: I think the problem is that the LEFT JOIN creates NULLs, not that table2 contain NULLs

Comment: @adrianm you are right,left join creates the null and i want them to be 0 or anything else but not NULL

Comment: Right, sorry, skimmed a little too fast through your question there, I updated my answer to account for both possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

IS the update even needed?

```
SELECT T1.*, coalesce(t2.IDREL,0) as IDREL 
FROM TABLE1 T1
Left JOIN Table2 ON TABLE1.ID=Table2.IDRel
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
 UPDATE Table2 SET IDRel = 0 where IDRel is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IS NUll`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1

Left JOIN Table2 ON TABLE1.ID=Table2.IDRel

UPDATE Table2 SET IDRel = 0 where IDRel IS  NULL
```